# How do I get the row with minimum value in a column using Diesel?

Tags: sql, rust, orm, rust-diesel

How do I get the row with the minimum value using the Diesel ORM? I want it to generate a query looking like this

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM TableName tbl
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT Id, MIN(Point) MinPoint
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Id
  ) tbl1
  ON tbl1.id = tbl.id
WHERE tbl1.MinPoint = tbl.Point
```

Answer (score 1):

Without extending the dsl provided by diesel it is only possible to express this query via [`sql_query`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.4/diesel/fn.sql_query.html).

Applied to this example this leads to the following query:

```rust
sql_query("
SELECT tbl.*
FROM TableName tbl
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT Id, MIN(Point) MinPoint
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Id
  ) tbl1
  ON tbl1.id = tbl.id
WHERE tbl1.MinPoint = tbl.Point
").load::<ResultType>(&conn)?
```

where `ResultType` is a type that implements [`QueryableByName`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.4/diesel/deserialize/trait.QueryableByName.html)